# Integrate : $\int \frac{1}{x^{2} \sqrt{2x-x^{2}}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Integrate :

$$I = \int \frac{1}{x^{2} \sqrt{2x-x^{2}}} dx$$

My attempt : substitute $\sin t = x-1$, $u = \tan \frac{t}{2}$

$$I = \int \frac{1}{x^{2} \sqrt{1-(x-1)^{2}}} dx = \int \frac{1}{(\sin t + 1)^{2} \cos t} \cos t dt$$

$$= \int \frac{1}{(\sin t + 1)^{2}} dt = \int \frac{2(u^{2}+1)}{(u+1)^{4}} du$$

$$= 2 \int \left(\frac{1}{(u+1)^{2}} - \frac{2}{(u+1)^{3}} + \frac{2}{(u+1)^{4}} \right)$$

$$= - \frac{2}{u+1} + \frac{2}{(u+1)^{2}} - \frac{4}{3(u+1)^{3}} + const.$$

$$= \frac{-2(3u^{2}+3u+2)}{3(u+1)^{3}} + const.$$

where

$$A = \sqrt{2x-x^{2}},~~ u = \sqrt{\frac{1-A}{1+A}}$$

However, Wolfram gives the following answer :

$$ - \frac{\sqrt{2x-x^{2}}~(x+1)}{3x^{2}} + const. $$

which is way more simple than mine. Is there any other way to integrate this? The $u$ in my answer is very complicated, I just couldn't change my answer into Wolfy's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$I = \int \frac{1}{x^{2} \sqrt{2x-x^{2}}} dx$$

$$I = \int \frac{1}{x^{3} \sqrt{\frac{2}{x}-1}} dx$$

Substitute $\displaystyle u=\frac{1}{x}$ to get

$$I=-\int\frac{u}{\sqrt{2u-1}}du$$

$$-2I=\int\frac{2u-1+1}{\sqrt{2u-1}}du$$

Can you finish it now?

Answer (score 1):

If $x>0,$

Let $1-x=\cos2t,dx=2\sin2t\ dt$

so we get $$\int\dfrac{dt}{\sin^4t}dt=\int(\cot^2t+1)\csc^2t\ dt$$

Can you take it home from here?

Answer (score 1):

If $x<0$ then $\sqrt{2x-x^{2}}$ does not make sense on $\mathbb{R}$ so I suppose that $x>0$, we have
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{1}{x^{2}\sqrt{2x-x^{2}}}{\rm d}x&=\int \frac{1}{x^{2}\sqrt{1-(x-1)^{2}}}{\rm d}x\\&\overset{x\mapsto x-1}{=}\int \frac{1}{(x+1)^{2}\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{\rm d}x\\&\overset{x\mapsto \sin x}{=}\int \frac{1}{(1+\sin x)^{2}}{\rm d}x\\&\overset{x\mapsto \tan \frac{x}{2}}{=}\int \frac{2}{(x^{2}+1)\left(1+\frac{2x}{x^{2}+1}\right)^{2}}{\rm d}x\\&=2\int \frac{1+x^{2}}{(1+x)^{4}}{\rm d}x\\&=2\int \left(\frac{1}{(x+1)^{2}}-\frac{2}{(x+1)^{3}}+\frac{2}{(x+1)^{4}} \right){\rm d}x\\&=-\frac{2}{3}\left( \frac{3x^{2}+3x+2}{(x+1)^{3}}\right)+C\\&\overset{\text{returning}}{=}-\frac{\sqrt{2x-x^{2}}(x+1)}{3x^{2}}+C
\end{align*}

Details of "returning":

\begin{align*}
-\frac{2}{3}\left( \frac{3x^{2}+3x+2}{(x+1)^{3}}\right)+C&=\frac{\sec^{2}\frac{x}{2}(-3\sin x +\cos x -5)}{3\left(\tan \frac{x}{2}+1\right)^{3}}+C\\
&=\frac{(-3\sin \sin^{-1} x +\cos\sin^{-1}x -5)\sec^{2}\frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}x)}{3(\tan \frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}x +1)^{3}}+C\\
&=\frac{2(\sqrt{1-x^{2}}+1)^{2}(\sqrt{1-x^{2}}-3x-5)}{3(\sqrt{1-x^{2}}+x+1)^{3}}+C\\&=\frac{2(\sqrt{-(x-2)x}+1)^{2}(-3x+\sqrt{-(x-2)x}-2)}{3(x+\sqrt{-(x-2)x})^{3}}+C\\&=-\frac{\sqrt{2x-x^{2}}(x+1)}{3x^{2}}+C
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align} \int \frac{1}{x^{2} \sqrt{2x-x^{2}}} dx
=& -\int\frac1{2-x}\ d\bigg[\left(\frac{2-x}{3x}\right)^{3/2}\bigg]\\
\overset{ibp}=& -\frac{\sqrt{2-x}}{3x^{3/2}}
+\frac13\int\frac1{x \sqrt{2x-x^{2}}}dx\\
= & -\frac{\sqrt{2-x}}{3x^{3/2}}-\frac{\sqrt{2-x}}{3x^{1/2}}+C
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "$\tan\frac x2$ substitution",

$\begin{align}
\int\frac{1}{(\sin t+1)^2}dt&=\int\frac{1}{\left(\cos(\frac\pi 2 -t)+1\right)^2}dt\\
&=\int\frac14\sec^4(\frac\pi 4-\frac t2)dt\\
&=-\frac12\left(\frac13\tan^3(\frac\pi 4-\frac t2)+\tan(\frac\pi 4-\frac t2)\right)+c\\
&=-\frac12\left(\frac13\left(\sqrt{\frac{2-x}{x}}\right)^3+\sqrt\frac{2-x}{x}\right)+c\\
&=-\frac12\sqrt\frac{2-x}{x}\left(\frac{2-x}{3x}+1\right)+c\\
&=-\frac{(x+1)\sqrt{2-x}}{3x^{3/2}}+c
\end{align}$